# Recovering access to an organization

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops

Currently, the company I work for maintains several popular vscode extensions. However, after the VSCode Marketplace publisher token generation has been moved to Azure, we've dont have any way to access the organization which corresponds to the Marketplace publisher in order to generate new publishing tokens. We have no idea who has access to the Azure account within the company.
How can we gain access to the organization page?

Answer (score 1):

Send an email to: Visual Studio Marketplace. (VSMarketplace@microsoft.com)

They can help you with the available options.