# How to get access to an Azure DevOpps Organization

Tags: azure-devops, organization

I cannot create a new organization named ''OnLineO'', as this name already exists.

I'm about sure it's me who created it a few time ago, but none of my logons run.

Must I send an email to Visual Studio Marketplace (VSMarketplace@microsoft.com) as stated in this post : [Recovering access to an organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543666/recovering-access-to-an-organization) ?

Answer (score 0):

Through the query, I found that your organization:"OnLineO" has been backed up to AAD:"OnLineO".

Please go to [azure DevOps profile page](https://aex.dev.azure.com/go/profile/?campaign=o%7Emsft%7Eold%7Evsts%7Eprofile),switch to `OnLineO` domain and try to login. Please do this in the new incognito window of browser. Note that your login account also needs to be backed up to AAD.

If you still cannot log in, please provide vsid as shown below. Pay attention to the processing of personal privacy information.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. If organization OnLineO is backed up to AAD "OnLineO", this is a great info, but I don't understand what it means... ?

On my DevOps profile page in an Invited session in Chrome (more isolated than incognito in other browsers), I am switched to OnLineO
[DevOps profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztDe9.png)

It's when I try to create OnLineO as a New Organization that I get this message :
[New Organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIsJY.png)

Comment: By inquiry, your account(christian.fumey@onlineo.fr) has not been added to the OnLineO organization.You need to contact the organization administer to add you to the organization.

Comment: Hi Hugh, I think I'm also the organization administer as christian@fumey.fr. What must I do ?

Comment: You need to use your administrator account to add the account(christian.fumey@onlineo.fr) to `Users` in the Organization settings.

Comment: Unfortunately none of my 4 accounts (2 AAD + 2 MSA) I use gives me access to https://dev.azure.com/onlineo Org. Trying to log as christian@fumey.fr, I sent an access request, and... I received it in christian@fumey.fr mailbox !!! But when I try to use the included link https://onlineo.visualstudio.com/, I get the "401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access." page... When trying to log with the MSA christian.fumey@outlook.com, same 401 but no button to request access. What could be done ?

Comment: Perhaps found a way to get access. From another Org linked to AAD OnLineO, I have downloaded Azure DevOps organizations connected to this OnLineO directory. And found that the owner of the onlineo Org is christian@fumey.org, a logon I used years ago, before I buy and switch to fumey.fr domain. Unfortunately, now this AAD account no more exists and christian@fumey.org is an alias of christian@fumey.fr. That's why I received the access request. I cannot logon with christian@fumey.org, so what can I do ?